# Is it possible to launch multiple servers listening to a different IP socket address?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying to launch multiple servers, at once, in a c program. For the sake of simplicity let's say 5 servers.
If I understand well the sockets, each of them must be listening to a different IP socket address (different PORT, different IP interface address).

I thought to do that inside a loop, incrementing port number by **i** at each turn. Here's my current code just to launch one server. I know it's possible with bash by launching the same process in background, but in C I really don't know how to do that and if it's even possible

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>


long PORT;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    /* 1. Open a socket 
       2. Bind to a address(and port).
       3. Listen for incoming connections.
       4. Accept connections 
       5. Read/Send 
    */

    int listenerSocket; /* socket for accepting connections    */
    int clientSocket; /* socket connected to client          */
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in client; /* client address information          */
    char buf[100]; /* buffer for sending & receiving data */  
    int errnum;

    listenerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(listenerSocket == -1){
        perror("erreur lors de la création du socket");
    }

    PORT = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port= htons(PORT);

    if (bind(listenerSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))     < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    puts("Server waiting for connection...");

    while(1){
        if (listen(listenerSocket, 5) < 0){
            perror("listen failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
    int c = sizeof(client);

    if((clientSocket = accept(listenerSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &c)) < 0){
        puts("error accepting the request");
        perror("Accept()");
    }
    puts("connection accepted");
    

    while(1){

    if( recv(clientSocket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0) < 0) {
        errnum = errno;
        perror("Recv()");
        printf("val printed by errno: %d\n",errno);
    }


    printf("Message : %s\n", buf); 


    }
    if (send(clientSocket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Send()");
        exit(7);
    }


    close(clientSocket);
    close(listenerSocket);

    printf("Server ended successfully\n");
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: At least use `getaddrinfo` and support IPv6 instead of using decades old ways to set up sockets.

Comment: It can be multiple ports on the same address.

Comment: There's nothing to preclude you from running nearly any number of servers other than limited OS resources. Tip: Write a *function* to create the server, returning a struct with all the state information preserved, and another that can handle incoming connections and break those out to separate structures that a third function handles.

Comment: Tip: Get a [good reference book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_Network_Programming) on this subject if you want to do it the "classic" way, or start familiarizing yourself with [kqueue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue), [epoll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) or an abstraction layer built on those for a more modern approach. Async networking is clearly the way to build scalable applications going forward.

Comment: 1. Open 5 sockets. 2. Bind to the same address and 5 different ports. 3. Listen for incoming connections. 4. Accept connections (you'll have to use `poll` or `select` to see which one to accept from!)